# How to map /etc/ssh/sshd_config as a volume in Docker's panubo/sshd?

Tags: docker, sshd

Notice that [panubo/sshd](https://hub.docker.com/r/panubo/sshd) is a docker image.  (It seems to be the highest rated one, which is why I chose it.)

I've been able to run it just fine --- doing various things.  What I can't seem to do it is to replace its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with my own.  Notice this is supported.  The [homepage says](https://github.com/panubo/docker-sshd)

> Configure the container with the following environment variables **or optionally mount a custom sshd config at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`**:

I'd like to replace it because I want to set directives such as `ListenAddress`.  Whenever I try to replace it, I get the following error:

```
#docker run -v $(pwd)/sshd_config:/etc/ssh/sshd_config docker.io/panubo/sshd:latest
> Starting SSHD
>> Generating new host keys
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
error: Failed to execute command
saving failed (run 'errors' for details)
#
```

At first I tried using my own `sshd_config`, which works in my machine.  But since my machine and this docker image are running two different versions of SSHd, I decided to empty the sshd_config file so that it assumes all defaults.  But it fails in the same way.  I don't know how to get the details of the error, so getting such errors would be an answer to this question as well.

**Output of DEBUG=true** as per @DavidMaze's idea.

```
#docker run -v $(pwd)/sshd_config:/etc/ssh/sshd_config -e DEBUG=true docker.io/panubo/sshd:latest
> Starting SSHD
+ DAEMON=sshd
+ echo '> Starting SSHD'
++ ls -A /etc/ssh
>> Generating new host keys
+ '[' '!' 'moduli
ssh_config
sshd_config' ']'
+ ls '/etc/ssh/keys/ssh_host_*'
+ ls '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*'
+ echo '>> Generating new host keys'
+ mkdir -p /etc/ssh/keys
+ ssh-keygen -A
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
+ mv /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub /etc/ssh/keys/
+ set_hostkeys
+ printf '%s\n' 'set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/HostKey[1] /etc/ssh/keys/ssh_host_rsa_key' 'set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/HostKey[2] /etc/ssh/keys/ssh_host_dsa_key' 'set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/HostKey[3] /etc/ssh/keys/ssh_host_ecdsa_key' 'set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/HostKey[4] /etc/ssh/keys/ssh_host_ed25519_key'
+ augtool -s
error: Failed to execute command
saving failed (run 'errors' for details)
#
```

Comment: That image runs [this entrypoint script](https://github.com/panubo/docker-sshd/blob/master/entry.sh); does adding a `-e DEBUG=true` option before the image name give you any more details on what's going wrong?  (At a guess, it's trying to write the host-key location into the sshd configuration and failing; providing host keys externally would fix this.)

Comment: That debug variable is just for the shell.  I'm updating the question with the output.  Maybe that rings you any bells?  It's unclear even which program is blowing those errors.  It looks like it's not `sshd`, which is good.  Since what I'm doing is supported by the image `panubo/sshd`, there must be something simple I'm doing wrong and there's probably an easy fix.  Thanks for your insights.  It's been useful!

Comment: That output suggests the `augtool` command is failing.  That's not a standard Unix tool; do you have its source or any way to debug it?

Comment: Yes, I had never seen this tool.  I installed it from APT --- the system is an Ubuntu one.  I will try to figure out how to reproduce this error message and will look into the source code to see if I can understand what's happening --- and therefore be able to fix it.  But it seems odd that no one had come across a problem like that before.  (This is the SSHd image most popular in Docker Hub.)  I believe I'd find that I'm just using Docker improperly instead of being a bug in the image.  But let's see.  I'll learn how to use augtool to see if some insight comes up.  I'll report back!  Thanks!

Comment: The [augtool](https://augeas.net/docs/index.html) is interesting, but it doesn't seem trivial enough for me to even reproduce the problem.  This leaves me with two options: (1) make changes to this image to try to dodge the problem --- I could insert my own custom configuration and remove augtool from the image or (2) use a different image.  I'm going to try (2) first.  Seems easiest at this point.  (I have zero experience making changes to a Docker.)

Comment: The mapping takes place just fine using a [different image](https://hub.docker.com/r/danchal/sshd).  Now, of course, I'm left without the facilities of that nice panubo/sshd image.  But at least I can move forward.  I need the host keys to be kept the same (so that users are not alarmed every time they connect, only the first) and also set up users, turn off shell access and this kind of stuff.  More work, but at least we are moving.  Thanks for your help!